# Import files in python on loop for data processing

Tags: python, loops, pdf

I am trying to extract data from about 100 pdfs and put them in a csv. I have successfully figured out the extraction part, but is there a way to import each pdf and have the code run it on a loop, so I don't have to manually change the target pdf and run the code for each pdf file? I am completely lost, as I haven't ever used glob or os modules

Comment: At this point, isn't an internet search the first step?

Answer (score 0):

listdir() from os should get everything that's in a folder / directory. (files and folders / directories)

If you want just files:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path_to_pdf_dir = 'your path here'
all_stuff = listdir(path_to_pdf_dir)
pdfs = []  # Empty list to store pdfs

for doc in all_stuff:
    if isfile(join(path_to_pdf_dir, doc)) and 'pdf' in doc:
        pdfs.append(doc)
```

This assumes all your pdfs are in a single directory.

Comment: You don't even need to split it. You can just do ('pdf' in doc)

Comment: True true @Casper_Gamer